# How would I add a row count that resets for each ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add a column to a sql table that counts how many rows per ID.  Some IDs may just have 1 result while others may have 3+.

What's the most efficient way to handle this?

Comment: There's only one way to add a column to a table, using `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Is this really what you need? Over time, I think you're going to have to update your table a lot to keep your counts consistent... It would be much easier as a view or simple select...

Comment: Why do you need to add a column? Why not just calculate it using `select ID, count(*) from whatever group by ID` or similar which is far preferable to maintaining denormalized data.

Comment: Seems like what you really need here is a `VIEW` though.

Answer (score 1):

In a query, you can use:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
from t;
```

This is probably the simplest method.  You can wrap a view around this.  You can also create a materialized view.

If you actually need a column, then you have two choices for keeping it up-to-date:

1. Triggers, to update the value each time a row is inserted, deleted, or updated.
2. A user-defined function and a computed column.